# Navigation Drawer unables clicks on page (Android Studio)

Tags: java, android, android-layout, onclick, navigation-drawer

So basicly we implemented a Navigation Drawer to our project yesterday and since we can't click on items on our page anymore, as if the drawer still overlays the page even when closed enabling us to click on anything on the page. Is there a way to enable clicking on the elements below this "closed" navigation drawer?

Here's a sniplet of one of our pages using the Navigation Drawer, we're unable to click the single switchbutton even when the drawer is closed.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.cocacola.fastgids.SettingsActivity">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/my_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:elevation="4dp"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"/>

    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true" tools:openDrawer="start"
        android:elevation="4dp"
        >

        <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView android:id="@+id/nav_view"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="start" android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main" app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />
    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/setting_Bootanim"
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_marginLeft="22dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="22dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/my_toolbar"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="28dp" />

    <Switch
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/switchAnimation"
        android:checked="true"
        android:text="Disable/Enable"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="21dp" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first element in your layout when you want to use a navigation drawer, should always be a drawerlayout. Taken from the official Android developer site:

> To add a navigation drawer, declare your user interface with a
>   DrawerLayout object as the root view of your layout.

I would highly suggest that you read [this](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html) from the official android site, and redo your code.

Comment: Thanks alot, stuck on this for two days, other people made that part of the code so I had no idea at all how to correctly use it, sorry for makeing such a dummy mistake

Comment: @Akorna No worries, and just a tip if you will develop android applications in the future - always check the official android documentation first, you won't find better documentation than that.

Answer (score 0):

don't add new View in DrawerLayout, it could intercept touch event.